# I want to hide undefined variables in a google map pop up

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, hide, undefined

Alright, I have a custom google map with clustered markers. I have some variables in place to populate the pop up windows for each marker. Basically, some pop up windows will need a variety of different fields of data. If one of the variables that populates the pop up window for a marker is removed I am left with an "undefined" result, and I would rather not just put a space in there if there is no data for it.

I feel like there is a really easy solution and I'm just stumbling over the syntax. I thikn I just need something that says, if this var "data.locations[i].ALbed" returns undefined, display:none

a plotted marker looks like this:

{"longitude": -81.489682, "latitude": 41.414132, "id":"5352","name":"Saber Health Care Group","loaction":"Hendricks County, IN", "operator":"Life Care Services",   "facility":"SNF & AL", "SNbed":"XX", "ALbed":"XX",}

the pop up script looks like this:

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {

                var contentTxt = '<b>' + data.locations[i].name + '</b>' + '<br />' 
        + data.locations[i].loaction + '<br />Operator: ' + data.locations[i].operator + '<br />Facility: '
        + data.locations[i].facility + '<br />SN beds: '+ data.locations[i].SNbed + '<br /> AL beds: ' + data.locations[i].ALbed;

              infowindow.setContent(contentTxt);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));

        markers.push(marker);             

      }
      var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);


  }
```

the current map can be seen here: http://neiltanderson.com/test/

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
var context2 = '';

['name', 'location', 'facility'].forEach(function (n) {
    if (data[n]) {
        context2 = context2 + '<b>' + n + '</b><br/>' + data[n] + '<br/>';
    }
});
```

here in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y35W/)

Comment: I am not sure I understand this code, and I am not sure what I need to add to get it to work. I basically want something that says, "if undefined $(this).hide;"

Answer (score 0):

This will check if the variable is undefined. You can then do your logic in there.

```
var someVar;
typeof(someVar) === 'undefined' ? console.log('is undefined') : console.log('is defined');
// Will log "is undefined" in this case
```

Edit: you can also do something like that

```
var contentTxt;

if(data.locations[i].name !== 'undefined') {

    contentTxt += '<b>' + data.locations[i].name + '</b>';
}

...

infowindow.setContent(contentTxt);
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. I'm still having trouble here though.

    var LTC;
   typeof(LTC) === 'undefined' ? console.log('is undefined') : console.log('is defined');
   // Will log "is undefined" in this case

   if LTC = 'undefined',
    $(this).hide();
    
 adding this to the info window script broke the whole map